# Visual Studio 2017, experimental/optional - No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++14

How I can enable using this header in my application. Header not found in folder /experimental/. What I should install/enable?

Environment:
Visual Studio 2017, v15.4.1, C++ Language Standard = ISO C++14 Standard

Comment: VS has never supplied that header, only C++17's `optional`.